# How to run a script embedded as an attribute in a DOM element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, d3.js

I'm using a great visualization library called d3 and I'm finding myself with code that looks very much like the following all over the place:

```
<span id="sparkline"></span>
<script type="text/javascript">
  drawSparkline('#target', [10, 20, 30, 40]);
  // or
  drawSparkline('#target', 'http://data.com/location'));
</script>
```

Is there a way to make this more expressive by embedding the code that acts on the dom element directly as an attribute?  Perhaps something like this:

```
<span onload="drawSparkline(this, [10, 20, 30, 40])"></span>
<span onload="drawSparkline(this, 'http://data.com/location')"></span>
```

Perhaps something like:

```
<span data-onload="drawSparkline(this, [10, 20, 30, 40])"></span>
```

With something at the beginning in jQuery like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('*[data-onload]').each( eval the onload? );
});
```

What would be the appropriate way?

Answer (score 1):

I would be more explicit about the different types of data that you're encoding:

```
<span class="sparkline" data-values="10,20,30,40"></span>
<span class="sparkline" data-url="http://data.com/location"></span>
```

Then, when you're iterating over them, check for specific types of data:

```
$(".sparkline").each(function() {
    var $source = $(this),
        values = $source.data("values"),
        url = $source.data("url");
    if (values) {
        // JSON.parse() is okay too, but if you're just
        // encoding lists of numbers this will be faster
        var data = values.split(", ").map(parseFloat);
        drawSparkline(this, data);
    } else if (url) {
        var that = this;
        $.ajax(url)
            .then(function(data) {
                drawSparkline(that, data);
            });
    }
});
```

I'd also suggest that you check out [Sparky](http://prag.ma/code/sparky/) (it's [on github](https://github.com/shawnbot/sparky)) if you want to save yourself some time and have them work in IE. :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using eval you could identify the spans with a class like this:

```
<span class="sparkLine" data-sparkdata="[10, 20, 30, 40]"></span>
<span class="sparkLine" data-sparkdata="http://data.com/location"></span>
```

and then, with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.sparkLine').each( function(){
      drawSparkline(this, $(this).data("sparkdata"));
   });
});
```

Comment: Sometimes are sparklines, some other times are mini pie charts.  Having classes for all of them seem odd.

Comment: Oh, well, you can do $('[data-sparkdata]') instead of $('.sparkLine') and the same code will work (or, if you can, $("something").find('[data-sparkdata]') )

Comment: I think this is a pretty good approach, but note that you're getting a string from the attribute, so in the array case you'll need to do something like `JSON.parse($(this).data(sparkdata))`.

Comment: I'm testing this approach, but I would really like to have something that would work for any javascript snippet.  I might have to go with the eval version unless I can find something more secure.

Comment: @nrabinowitz jQuery does that by himself, check this http://goo.gl/5Z7mV .
I don't know if it can help you, but you can add an attribute that can be the method itself and then use that, quick example:
window[jQuert("#something").data("method")]()